# Javascript - When does the result of a promise become available, once it has been resolved?

Tags: javascript, promise

After a promise has been resolved and we can use the .then method on it, when does it run? Does it run as soon as it has been resolved? For instance, in the following example the promise is "ready" as soon as Javascript comes to it, rite? There's nothing big happening. Since there is no big computation going on in the promise, why do does the .then method run after everything else? Thanks

```
  let $body = $('#mainBlock');
let checker = true;

let testPromise = new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject)
    {
       if(checker)
       {
            resolve();
            $body.append('<p>CodeHasFinished</p>');
       }
    }
);




$body.append('<p>before</p>');

testPromise.then(function(){
     $body.append('<p>middle</p>');
});

$body.append('<p>after</p>');

/*

Result added to body->
CodeHasFinished
before
after
middle

*/
```

Comment: `.then()` is not guaranteed to return result synchronously

Comment: Should I assume that {.then} will run after everything else? Thanks

Comment: Try not to "assume" anything, here. If you want to use `Promise` chain, chain `.then()` and `.catch()` and perform tasks within the functions passed to `.then()` and `.catch()`; if you want to use synchronous code, use synchronous code. Why are you trying to synchronize synchronous code with asynchronous code? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: .then is actually "*guaranteed*" to be called asynchronously - I put guaranteed in quotes because some "promises" are more compliant than others - see the Note 3.1 in [the spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#notes)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/)

> 2.2.4. onFulfilled or onRejected must not be called until the execution context stack contains only platform code. [3.1]

Note 3.1 states

> Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise implementation code. In practice, this requirement *ensures that onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously*, after the event loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack....

So, in a sense your comment that .then will run "after everything else" is a good assumption

Consider the following code

```js
let i = 0;
console.log('a', ++i);
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('e', ++i)).then(() => console.log('h', ++i)).then(() => console.log('j', ++i));
console.log('b', ++i);
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('f', ++i)).then(() => console.log('i', ++i));
console.log('c', ++i);
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('g', ++i));
console.log('d', ++i);
```

I can be sure that the console output will be

- a 1
- b 2
- ...
- j 10

To be clear, if one of those `.then` functions had asynchronous code within it (that returned a Promise), the sequence would **not** be as simple to predict - I'm merely demonstrating that your "assumption" - *that `.then` will run after everything else* - is actually quite a reasonable one